# Facebook: which token is suited to read from an open group

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am starting with the Facebook Graph API, however I am really confused by their access policies. When compared to Google, Facebook is just terrible at providing information and guidelines about using their API.

I have a C# application and would like to access the events of several public groups. The application is not connected to Facebook login, so no Facebook user is associated to the Grpah API calls. I am using traditional HTTP requests to get the data:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{group_id}/events?access_token={access_token}
```

I was able to get an access token from the Facebook Graph Explorer. However, I am absolutely buffled by these two questions:

- Which [access tokens and permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens) do I need for an app without Facebook login to be able to access the data?
- How do I acquire and renew this token?

When trying to simply call `GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{group_id}/events`, I get an error saying `An access token is required to request this resource.`, even though the requested group is public.

Comment: How is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/group/events not absolutely clear on what permission you need?

Comment: As I mentioned multiple times in my post, I do not use Facebook login, thus I do not have the user access token for a member of the group. As I am able to see the group events even without being logged in, I would expect the same behaviour for apps. Google, for comparison, enables to embed an application-wide access token directly into the app. I am looking for a similar approach in the Facebook API, however, I am unable to find it.

Comment: You are unable to find it, because it doesn't exist. Your assumption of _"if it is available right there on the web site, it must be available without any restrictions via API"_ is simply wrong. So you either go and get your self the token with the permission the documentation says you need - or you don't. Your choice.

Comment: "So you either go and get your self the token with the permission the documentation says you need"... but this is exactly what I am asking. How am I supposed to get a user access token when no user is logged to Facebook in my app?

Comment: _"but this is exactly what I am asking"_ - and that's why I keep telling you that you are asking for the wrong thing. You need a user access token, so you get yourself one. If you are not creating this app for your own use or you are not a member of the groups you want to read the feed from, then you will have to implement Facebook login; but if you only need it for yourself, then you could get away with simply generating an access token via Graph API Explorer and extending it by doing the necessary requests "manually". [...]

Comment: [...] For how long you can extend an access token and when you will have to repeat the process (which at this point becomes easier if you actually implement Facebook login, even if for your own use only) etc. is explained in detail in the documentation.

Comment: Oh, so Facebook does not provide the API without a login? That is really a flawed approach. I did not think even for a second Facebook would force the users to log in. Even then, the documentation says the events are available only to the members of a group (even a public one)! This is just plain stupid. Thank you, CBroe, and sorry for the confusion. I was just expecting a much more professional approach from such a large company. It seems I will have to parse the HTML from regular requests to Facebook groups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As CBroe has enlightened me, Facebook forces developers to use Facebook login in order to access group API. Even then, only group members are able to display the events of a group (even a public group)! Because of these restrictions, Facebook Graph API is utterly useless to me. I will have to rely on parsing the HTML response from regular requests to Facebook pages.

Tl;Dr, the following 3 facts:

1. there is no direct solution to my problem
2. the "right" way is to use Facebook login and then follow the official steps from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/group/events
3. the only possible workaround without Facebook login is parsing the response HTML